# Why Concrete5 website answers with an error 500 after running c5:clear-cache?

Tags: caching, concrete5

The [Concrete5 documentation](https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/appendix/cli-commands) says:

> Clearing the concrete5 cache is as easy as executing this command:
>
> ```
> concrete/bin/concrete5 c5:clear-cache
> ```

But after running this command as root the website answers with an error 500. Why?

Comment: You should run the concrete5 CLI commands using the same user used by your web server. For example, on Ubuntu with Apache you can run the command `sudo -u www-data -- /path/to/concrete/bin/concrete5`

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. It would be nice if it were in the documentation.

Comment: the concrete5 documentation available at https://documentation.concrete5.org is a community project: everyone can contribute to it. If you want to fix the relevant documentation page, just login with your concrete5 account and click the "Edit Page" button on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable error display you will see:

> Cache path is not writable

The `c5:clear-cache` command doesn't give write permissions on the cache path to the web server.

You can solve this by resetting the correct ownership with:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/concrete5/application/files/ 
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/concrete5/application/config/
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/concrete5/packages/
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/concrete5/updates/
```